# Adding 2 column values to sql existing table

Tags: sql

I really appreciate someone can help with this as I have been trying to solve for ages, I have an sql table called invoiceItems the table is really simple and has 3 columns (invoiceId, productId, productQuantity) I will need this information later to update the stock table, and as I don't know how many many items are going to be selected in the sale so i have a stored procedure that creates the invoice first then passes the invoiceId to another stored procedure that I am trying to develop, and because i dont know how many items are going to be sold so I am passing 2 parameters to the stored procedure with the type nvarchar(max) like this

```
DECLARE @productId NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @productQuantity NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4'
SELECT CAST(value AS INT) as productId FROM STRING_SPLIT(@productId, ',')
SELECT CAST(value AS decimal(10,1)) as productQuantity from STRING_SPLIT(@productQuantity, ',')
```

this returns two coulmns, how I can insert these values along with the @invoiceId in the invoiceItems table

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. (And an additional fiddle helps too, e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/ can be used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will always put the productId and matching productQuantity in the same order per variable, here is a multi CTE joined on the row number, and inserting a declared invoiceNumber to every line:

```
DECLARE @productId NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @productQuantity NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4'
DECLARE @invoiceNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) = '12345'

;WITH ProductIds AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        CAST(value AS INT) AS productId
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@productId, ',')
),
ProductQuantities AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS productQuantity
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@productQuantity, ',')
)
SELECT 
    P.productId,
    PQ.productQuantity,
    @invoiceNumber AS invoiceNumber
FROM 
    ProductIds P
JOIN 
    ProductQuantities PQ ON P.rn = PQ.rn
```

| productId | productQuantity | invoiceNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 2.2 | 12345 |
| 3 | 3.3 | 12345 |
| 4 | 4.4 | 12345 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/QuUQ2fEL)

To insert this into the invoiceItems table, simply swap out the SELECT statement with an INSERT statement:

```
DECLARE @productId NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1,2,3,4'
DECLARE @productQuantity NVARCHAR(MAX) = '1.1,2.2,3.3,4.4'
DECLARE @invoiceNumber NVARCHAR(MAX) = '12345'

;WITH ProductIds AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        CAST(value AS INT) AS productId
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@productId, ',')
),
ProductQuantities AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,
        CAST(value AS DECIMAL(10,1)) AS productQuantity
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(@productQuantity, ',')
)
INSERT INTO invoiceItems (productId, productQuantity, invoiceNumber)
SELECT 
    P.productId,
    PQ.productQuantity,
    @invoiceNumber AS invoiceNumber
FROM 
    ProductIds P
JOIN 
    ProductQuantities PQ ON P.rn = PQ.rn
```

Comment: that exactly achieves what I am looking for thanks a million. but how to insert this new table values to an existing table with the same schema.

Comment: Hi @RamySalem I've updated my answer above to include a version that will INSERT the values into the invoiceItems table.